# The approximation of a summation

Tags: summation, contest-math

In a recent Olympiad contest, a problem reduced to finding the greatest integer function of the summation of the reciprocals of square roots from 1 to 100.

$$\left\lfloor \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right\rfloor$$

Using some Cauchy, I showed that it was greater than 14 , but Wolfram Alpha says the answer is 18, which is quite far off. Is there any way to do it with elementary math? Even a calculus proof would be fine.

Comment: Did you try approximating with integral $\int _1 ^{100} \frac {1}{\sqrt {x}}dx $

Comment: That just gives 20.

Comment: What its $2\sqrt {x}=2 (10-1)=18$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have that $$\sqrt k-\sqrt{k-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt k+\sqrt{k-1}}>\frac{1}{2\sqrt k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt k+\sqrt{k}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt k+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$$
And
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100}\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k=\sqrt{101}-1>9$$
So we have that $$\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}>9\implies \sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}>18$$
We also have that $$\sum_{k=2}^{100}\sqrt k-\sqrt{k-1}=9$$
So we have that $$\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}<9\implies \sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}<18$$
So we have that $$1+\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<19$$

Comment: @Anish hey if you don't understand my answer or need more clarification feel free to comment, otherwise if my answer answered your question consider accepting it.